# how to read a google sheet from my drive without access token required in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, google-sheets-api

I am working on Laravel Project It require to add Google sheets & after add this it must be shareable at my site 
this my Code.
When I open the link
http://localhost:8000/viewsheet/18ioWbPXjd1RM2wqJuJ0eFzkYAfC03OT9_X5tWJEV3uU/sheet/Phrasebook
from another browser, it gives me an error because I am not logged in
how I can make it shareable for all users without others login?

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Sheets;
use Google;

class sheetview extends Controller
{
//
public function __invoke(Request $request, $spreadsheet_id, $sheet_id)
{

                    //// print_r($request);
                    // $rows = $request->user()
                    // ->sheets()
                    // ->spreadsheet($spreadsheet_id)
                    // ->sheet($sheet_id)
                    // ->get();


$user = $request->user();

$token = [
  'access_token'  => $user->access_token,
  'refresh_token' => $user->refresh_token,
  'expires_in'    => $user->expires_in,
  'created'       => $user->updated_at->getTimestamp(),
];

// all() returns array
$values = Sheets::setAccessToken($token)- >spreadsheet($spreadsheet_id)->sheet($sheet_id)->all();
print_r($values);

    ///$headers = $rows->pull(0);

   //   return view('sheets.viewsheet')->with(compact('headers', 'rows'));
    }
  }
```

Comment: Create a guest user and login as them - https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#other-authentication-methods

Comment: how to do this?